# Using Pandas AWS Glue Python Shell Jobs

Tags: python, pandas, aws-glue

The AWS Documentation 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-job-python.html

mentions that

> The environment for running a Python shell job supports the following
>   libraries:
>
> ...
>
> pandas (required to be installed via the python setuptools
>   configuration, setup.py)

But it does not mention how to make the install.

How can I use Pandas in a AWS Glue Python Shell Jobs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Goto https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-job-python.html#create-python-extra-library. Check section
   **To create a Python .egg or .whl file** for 'how to create setup file for python shell job'
2. In setup.py file, add line `install_requires=['pandas==0.25.1']`:

> ```
> setup(name="<module name>",
>         version="0.1",
>         packages=['<package name if any or ignore>'],
>         install_requires=['pandas==0.25.1']
>     )
> ```

I also wrote small shell script to deploy python shell job without manual steps to create egg file and upload to s3 and deploy via cloudformation. Script does all automatically.
You may find code at https://github.com/fatangare/aws-python-shell-deploy

Comment: Can you make it clearer ? Once you have setup.py, you pass it to the job definition using the "—extra-py-files" arguments ?

Comment: Check link shared above. It contains all steps. You should create .egg file using setup.py and pass it to "—extra-py-files" arguments

Answer (score 6):

Just to clarify Sandeep's answer, here is what worked for me

1/ Ignore AWS doc

2/ Create a setup.py file containing :

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name="pandasmodule",
        version="0.1",
        packages=[],
        install_requires=['pandas==0.25.1']
    )
```

3/ Run this command in the folder containing the file :

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

4/ Upload the .whl file to s3

5/ Configure the "Python lib path" in your Glue ETL Job to the s3 path

You can now use "`import pandas as pd`" in your Glue ETL Job

Comment: Can more than one package be included in setup.py? If so, could someone post an example?

Comment: sure you just add more module names, in the line "install_requires"

Answer (score 1):

No need to do anything, just import pandas and start using it.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Glue Python Shell, the following script works directly for pandas:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name="pandasmodule",
        version="0.1",
        packages=[],
        install_requires=['pandas==0.25.1']
    )

# use pandas
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([1, 3, 5, np.nan, 6, 8])

print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

AWS Glue 2.0 supports pandas—1.0.1
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/reduced-start-times-spark-etl-jobs.html

so in your script you can simply write : import pandas.
If you want to use other python module that is not provided in Glue, you can download .whl or .zip ->store it in S3 -> place path of it in glue job in "Python library path" and glue during a job run will do a pip install "yourmodule"