# AWS Glue: ModuleNofFoundError

Tags: python, pandas, aws-glue

In my glue script (Spark 3.1, Python 3, Glue 3) I'm trying to use `df.to_excel()` function from pandas library. Apparently pandas library has dependencies on `openpyxl`. My code is:

```
import sys
import boto3
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd

client = boto3.client('s3')
obj = client.get_object(Bucket = 'myBucketName', Key = 'myFileName.csv')

df = pd.read_csv(obj['Body'])

df.to_excel("output.xlsx", sheet_name='my-sheet-name')
```

Issue I'm having is getting error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'`

I found below links that explains how to add external python libraries:

 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-job-python.html#create-python-extra-library

 [Using Pandas AWS Glue Python Shell Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58399180/using-pandas-aws-glue-python-shell-jobs)

 Apparently I did something wrong because it doesn't work for me. My steps are:

1. Create setup.py file locally:

   from setuptools import setup

   setup(
   name="openpyxl",
   version="3.0.7",
   install_requires=['openpyxl']
   )
2. execute in my local directory `py setup.py develop` (I'm on Windows, my python version is 3.9.7)
3. execute in my local directory `py setup.py bdist_egg`
4. copy file `../dist/openpyxl-3.0.7-py3.9.egg` into my s3 bucket
5. in my glue job I put file location in `Python library path`

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the newer versions of glue can you skip the egg/wheel approach and install at runtime.  In the Job Parameters put a key "--additional-python-modules" and in the value put "openpyxl, pandas".

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/building-python-modules-from-a-wheel-for-spark-etl-workloads-using-aws-glue-2-0/